# Stages are getting deleted in Kanban View in odoo 10

Tags: view, odoo, kanban, odoo-10

I am working on kanban view of purchase order in which I used attribute “ default_group_by”  by this all the purchase orders comes in defined stages (i.e ‘po_stage)’

[image]

But when   PO has not any  define stage then that kanban view got deleted  from the view  as below

[image]

for that I used _group_by_full  attribute  as per [link](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/odoo-grouping-kanban-view-empty.html)

but this does not work for me so can you please suggested me how I can archive this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In odoo 10 `group_by_default` is replaced by `group_expand` and it takes list of all your stages.
for e.g your columns are `stage` and you want to show all empty stages.

```
@api.model
def _read_group_stage_ids(self,stages,domain,order):
    stage_ids = self.env['stage.stage'].search([])
    return stage_ids

stage = fields.Many2one('stage.stage', group_expand='_read_group_stage_ids')
```

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure you add `<kanban default_group_by="your_group_by_field">` , Also be sure that the inherited view does not have a default group_by , if so remove it.

Comment: `KeyError:u'_group_by_full'`